# Reversing and Splitting in Python

Tags: text-files, python-3.4

I have a file "names.txt". The contents are

```
"Smith,RobJones,MikeJane,SallyPetel,Brian"
```

and I want to read "names.txt" and make a new file "names2.txt" that looks like:

```
"Rob Smith Mike Jones Sally Jane Brian Petel"
```

I know I should be using `#rstrip(\n)` and `#.split(',')`

So far I have:

```
namesfile = input('Enter name of file: ') #open names.txt   
openfile = open(namesfile, 'r')
```

Comment: What do you want? The full answer?

Comment: yeah, i'm stuck on where to go next

Answer (score -1):

This will do exactly that. You might be able to polish this and make it more elegant and I encourage you to do so:

```
import re

with open('names.txt') as f:
    # Split the names
    names = re.sub(r'([A-Z])(?![A-Z])',r',\1',f.read()).split(',')
    # Filter empty results
    names = [n for n in names if  n != '']
    # Swap pairs with each other
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if((i+1)%2 == 0):
            names[i], names[i-1] = names[i-1], names[i]
    print ' '.join(names)
```